# Почему соект в sockaddr_in отличается?

Tags: c, unix-socket

Пишу простой клиент-сервер на сокетах. С помощью define указал номер порта на клиенте и сервере - 3490. заполнил структуру `struct addrinfo p`. Все работает. Вопрос в следующем: я хочу вывести номер порта, с которым работаю. первая мысль - `((struct sockaddr_in*)p->ai_addr)->sin_port` для IPv4. Но и клиент, и сервер выводят 41485. Разве он не должен совпадать с 3490, который я задавал?

Comment: [ntohl / htonl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl)

Comment: ты порядок байт перепутал либо при указании порта, либо при выводе.

Comment: спасибо. помогло.